# Can a Bokeh ColumnDataSource be plotted in one go like a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: bokeh

Can I plot a bokeh `ColumnDataSource` in one go, similar to plotting a Pandas DataFrame (e.g., second figure on [the Pandas plotting documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html)); especially if the ColumnDatasource is derived from a DataFrame? Or is the loss of e.g. the index preventing this?

So, with Pandas I can do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

years = np.arange(2000, 2020)
columns = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random((20, 4)), columns=columns, index=years)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I'd like some interactivity on that figure; in particular, hovering over the lines should show the y-value and the respective label name.

With Bokeh, I currently use:

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.palettes import Category20

output_notebook()
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600)

for column, color in zip(columns, Category20[4]):
    line = p.line(df.index, df[column], color=color, legend=column, name=column)
    p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers=[line], tooltips=[(column, "$y")], toggleable=False))
p.legend.background_fill_alpha = 0.5
show(p)
```

The separate `p.add_tools(...)` calls are so that the individual dataset labels and y-values show up when hovered over the corresponding line.

But the manual loop feels a tad unwieldy. I wonder if there is something available along the following lines:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p.multi_line(source=source, color=Category20[4])   
# or something similar to: p.multi_line(source=source, xs='index', ys=models)
```

where the index is automatically used for the x-axis, the columns are looped over, and the legend labels are derived from the column names.

The best alternative I've found appears to be

```
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
    x=[df.index]*len(columns),
    y=[df[column].values for column in columns],
    color=Category20[4],
    legend=columns))
p.multi_line(source=source, xs='x', ys='y', color='color')
show(p)
```

but that again feels unwieldy in creating the ColumnDatasource. Plus, I don't know how to create tooltips for each line individually: I guess multi-line isn't supposed to be used for lines that should be regarded individually.

Is there a more direct, easier, way?

Comment: p.add_tools(HoverTool( tooltips=[
    ("(x,y)", "($x, $y)"),

Comment: @Pallie Thanks, that solves a partial problem (I see I shouldn't have used a list (comprehension)). Is there any chance to squeeze in the name of the column into the tooltip as well? I've tried with `$name`, and adding `name=columns` to the creation of the source, but I keep getting stuck with "???" in the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

My previous comment did not come out at all like what I was trying to type.
I was trying to suggest:

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool( tooltips=[ ("X" ,"@x"), ("Y", "@y") ]))
```

Your `ColumnDataSource` construction seems fairly concise to me already.
As to your question in the comment, would adding

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool( tooltips=[ ("X" ,"$x"), ("Y", "$y"), ("Name" , "@legend")]))
```

do the trick?

Comment: I take it you mean `"$x"` and `"$y"`, instead of `"@X"` and `"@Y"`. I've tried a few variants of `("Name" , 'legend')`, `("Name" , 'name')` and `("Name" , '$name')` for the last tuple, to no avail: the `???` remains (`("Name" , legend)` is invalid, since `legend` is undefined).

Comment: $x" and "$y",  or "@X" and "@Y" annotations should both work I think, I made a mistake in my answer: legend should be "@legend"

Comment: "@legend" works; I had overlooked that option. `"@x"` will show *all* values for x (the complete array); similar for `"@y"`. So I need `"$x"` and `"$y"` to obtain a single x and y value for a point on a line.

Comment: NB: "fairly concise" is of course in the eye of the beholder. I don't really like the `[df[column].values for column in columns]` and the repeated `[df.index]*len(columns)` parts. My thinking is the ability to use `source = ColumnDataSource(df)` directly, possibly with added keys for the colors.

Comment: Yes you are right. I simply gave you the answer that I thought works. http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/models/sources.html#ColumnDataSource suggests there is a `ColumnDataSource(df)` syntax for constructing directly from pandas dataframes